# Copy all items from a cell or matrix into a new field in a structure (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, structure

I have a (probably) simple question (matlab newbie here).

How can I copy all the values from a field in a structure that contains either a cell or a matrix (let's say `words` or `times` in the example below) and add it to another structure. So, for example, the first item in the `words` cell array would go into new_structure(1).words, the second one into new_structure_words(2), etc...

```
>>textgrid_data(1)

ans = 
      speaker: 'N00535'
     time_beg: 0
     time_end: 224.3090
    ninterval: 602
        times: [552x2 double]
        words: {552x1 cell}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the third syntax in the [documentation for `deal`function](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/deal.html) (`[S.field] = deal(X)`)

```
[new_structure_words(1:numel(textgrid_data(1).words)).word]=deal(textgrid_data(1).words{:})
```

In a shorter form, if you want to use values from cell array `A` to fill the fields in structure array `B` use:

```
[B(1:numel(A)).word] = deal(A{:});
```

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia I believe there's no need for `deal` in this context (since version 7.0)

Comment: @EitanT Would you elaborate on that?

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia You could also do: `[B(1:numel(A)).word] = A{:}`